# What are some presentations that delve into the changes in academic publishing toward open access, pre-print archives, etc?

Tags: publishing, open-access

I am looking for slide desks, infographics, conference presentations, or blog posts that tease apart the shifting landscape of academic publishing and the ongoing battle between the "old guard" traditional publisher, and the range of new models that are being advanced, usually under the banner of "open access".

My objective here is to provide a balanced primer to my colleagues at an academic institution. I'm looking for sources that give a fair hearing to different view points, and that have nice figures I can reuse.

Comment: so you want anything about open access? pretty broad request.

Comment: I'm looking for a primer on how the academic publishing industry is in transition from traditional journals, to open access journal, pre-print archives, and other alternative models that may be emerging.

Comment: you basically just repeated your question. again, still seems like anything open access to me. also "emerging"...this has been going on for over a decade so i'm not sure what your definition of that is. i'll list some sources, see where that goes.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ban me for asking a too-general question? I know that we live in a society of rules, and there are punishments prescribed for transgressing against orderliness. I have assumed the position and am ready for punishment m'lord.

Comment: lol. while you think i'm being aggressive or trolling you, i'm actually trying to get you the information that you seek. i'm not asking because it is required or for my health. the avenues of openness, and the connections between them are incredibly exciting/interesting to me. it seems like, you are basically asking for anything supporting open access in the academic arena. and that is totally fine/legit question. the preprint keyword makes me think you want something more specific. hence all of this back and forth.

Comment: My objective here is to provide a balanced primer to my colleagues at an academic institution. I'm looking for sources that give a fair hearing to different view points, and that have nice figures I can reuse.

Comment: just want to follow up and apologize; believe it or not, i've actually switched up how i interact with people online to be more friendly/open. thought i was doing well, but clearly i still have more work to do. sorry if this seemed to be anything but me trying to get more information out of you. i will try harder/do better. my bad.

Comment: no worries man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community that certainly has specifically what you seek is [SPARC](https://sparcopen.org/). In particular their [open access](https://sparcopen.org/open-access/) section and its Open Access Impact Stories. It may be fruitful to ask this question in their google groups forums: [SPARC OA Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/arl.org/forum/#!forum/sparc-oaforum) and [SPARC Libraries & OER Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/arl.org/forum/#!forum/sparc-liboer).

Here's a non definitive list of open access resources that you can use too:
[Open Data Access Policies and Strategies in the European Research Area and Beyond](http://www.science-metrix.com/pdf/SM_EC_OA_Data.pdf)
[Ope Access, Open Education Resources and Open Data in Uganda](http://www.panafrican-med-journal.com/content/article/21/129/pdf/129.pdf)
[Open Access and Open Data: Similarities and Differences](https://vimeo.com/17302549)
[Open Access and Open Data: What Do I Need to Know (and Do)?](https://www.slideshare.net/martindonnelly/open-access-and-open-data-what-do-i-need-to-know-and-do)
[After Bill Gates Backs Open Access, Steve Ballmer Discovers the Joys of Open Data](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20170419/09104237185/after-bill-gates-backs-open-access-steve-ballmer-discovers-joys-open-data.shtml)
[Open Access, Open Data, Open Research? The challenges and opportunities of enabling public access to publicly funded research](https://www.slideshare.net/CameronNeylon/open-access-open-data-open-research-presentation)
[Open Data and Reproducible Research - Open Access at Nature Research](http://www.nature.com/openresearch/about-open-access/open-data/)
[Open Access and Open Data - Stanley Wood, Bill and Melinda Gates Foundation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j29Y8C-HkHY)
[Open Methods, Open Data, Open Access](http://www.apa.org/monitor/2012/11/open-methods.aspx)
[UMass Medical School Open Access Guide](http://libraryguides.umassmed.edu/OpenAccess/OpenData)
[Open Access, Open Data, Open Science...What Does "Openness" Mean in the First Place?](http://somatosphere.net/2015/02/open-science.html)

Answer (score 0):

List of references:

- "What are preprints?" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zMgY8Dx9co#action=share
- "What’s the deal with preprints?" http://blog.scielo.org/en/2016/11/22/whats-the-deal-with-preprints/#.WXY04nXysUE